# how to find out what file is being used by another process

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete few files and folders from `inetpub` and restore them from a different location, but I get the following error message:

> remove-item : Cannot remove item C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Admin\Views: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Admin\Views\' because it is being used by another process.
>   At C:\Development\PowerShells\Russia_RestoreFromBackups.ps1:54 char:2
>   +     remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

There is no IIS installed, so its just a replication of production server folder structure. Is there any way to find out which files are being used by which process?

```
get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Admin" -recurse | % {



remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force

}
start-sleep 5

get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Tablet" -recurse | % {
    if($_.Name -ne 'mediacontent')
    {

        remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the same error occur if you just use `Remove-Item "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Admin" -Recurse -Force`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what is locking the file. Open [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), Ctrl + F , type search string say 'Views' in the search box, click on Search. This should display a list of locks on items having 'Views' string in the name.

Comment: i just installed process explorer but when i enter any keyword say for example Russia or Admin or Views it does not give me any results back

Comment: if it doesn't return anything it means there is no lock. What happens if you try to delete the folder manually.

Comment: Just did the above but no results found, and also at the same time i am running powershell script and its giving me same error

Comment: i am able to delete the folders manualy, also i have full read write permissions on the folder#

Comment: I am sure there is something which is locking the file, could you put a break point in your script at the line where you are trying to delete, and then run the script. When it reaches the break point, try process explorer to see what is locking.

Comment: i have emailed you the script i have two break points, strange thing is everytime i run the script the locks varies i mean if i run the script 1st time the lock will be shown on admin/folder1 than second time it will be admin/folder2 and 3rd time it will run succesffully

Comment: Than if i close everything and start it again , same problem persists